# How to name the common length between two parallel lines

Tags: geometry, terminology

I don't know what does it called, or even theres some/any name of such geometric calculation. So I draw and paste it here. Can anybody tell me, what does the length between `A` and `B` in respect to Red and Brown line?

[common_length_between_two_lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjblI.jpg)

Comment: its not distance between lines, rather intersectioned length of two lines.

Answer (score 1):

The length between a pair of parallel lines is just called the distance; as far as I'm aware there's no special name for it.

Comment: thanks, I also do think, there's no particular name for this.